# posts_per_page=> 0 list all posts for a specific category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress webpage in which I want to show zero post for a specific category. Following is the code for that:

```
<?PHP
   $temp_args = [
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'orderby' => array(
           'feat_yes' => 'ASC',
           'post_type' => 'ASC',
           'date' => 'DESC'),
       'posts_per_page' => $data->{"no_articles_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE},     // Line A
       'tax_query' => [
           [
               'taxonomy' => 'category',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => $cat_today,
           ],
       ],

   ];
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp_args); echo '</pre>';
   $q = new WP_Query($temp_args);
   echo "Have posts: ";
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($q->have_posts()); echo '</pre>';
   if ($q->have_posts()) {
       while ($q->have_posts()) {
           $q->the_post();
           $post_type = strtolower(get_post_type());
           switch ($post_type) {
           }

       }
       wp_reset_postdata();
   }
   ?>
```

I have added **Line#A** in order to control to number of posts for a specific category. When the value of `'posts_per_page' => 0` then it shows all list of posts for that particular specific category which I am not sure why.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above when `'posts_per_page' => 0` then it should show zero post.

Comment: If you don't want to show any posts for a category, why are you looking up posts for that category? Just don't do a look-up. Wrap the search in an if block.

Comment: @stevecomrie can you let me know in an answer what I have to do ?

Comment: Why not use `'category__not_in'` in your original query?

Comment: Where do you want me to use `'category__not_in'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a longstanding bug in WordPress Core. See [Trac ticket #24142](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24142).

You can just make sure it's greater than 0 before running the code by wrapping everything in an if statement:

```
<?PHP
    if( $data->{"no_articles_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE} >= 1 ) {
        $temp_args = [
            'post_type' => array('current-channel', 'post', 'current-episodes'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => array(
                'feat_yes' => 'ASC',
                'post_type' => 'ASC',
                'date' => 'DESC'),
            'posts_per_page' => $data->{"no_articles_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE},     // Line A
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $cat_today,
                ],
            ],

        ];
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp_args); echo '</pre>';
        $q = new WP_Query($temp_args);
        echo "Have posts: ";
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($q->have_posts()); echo '</pre>';
        if ($q->have_posts()) {
            while ($q->have_posts()) {
                $q->the_post();
                $post_type = strtolower(get_post_type());
                switch ($post_type) {
                    case 'current-episodes':
                        get_template_part('template-parts/content-search', 'video');
                        break;
                    case 'current-channel':
                        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "current_portal_end_date_timestamp", true) > time()) {
                            echo "Hello World";
                            get_template_part('template-parts/content-search', 'channel');

                        }
                        break;
                    case 'post':
                        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'search');
                        break;
                }

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
?>
```